In tailwindCss config file, I have to add my own class names which will be consisting of tailwind classes. How to do that?
To use flex, I have to write flex justify-between items-center in all element classNames, but I have to make a general class let us say "flexBetween" which will have all these flex justify-between items-center properties and now instead of writing this much big class names, I can simply write className="flexBetween" in html elements props.
I wish to make dozens of such customised classes in my tailwind.config file. How to achieve it?
I tried getting it done by making utils file and there writing the customised string exports as the required class names but in tailwind.config file, I am not sure how to write it and in which object?

You can use components layer to add your custom classes. Here is an example:


// globals.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .custom-style {
    /* ... */
  }
}



For more details you can check the official docs

you can make use of the components layer in Tailwind to achieve this as it is a good place to put in your custom styles and to style any third-party components.
Here is what you need to add to your css file:


// index.css

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .flexBetween {
    @apply flex justify-between items-center;
  }
  
  /* ... */
}



Read more about the components layer in the Tailwind docs.
Cheers!
